# does java thread have to invoke stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a button that starts a thread, which i use to show that my system is processing.
with `thread1` i open a jdialog and to Show that my system is running. whereby i use `thread2` to close my jdialog with `dlg.dispose();`
my problem is, once my program stops running, i click the button again, then an error message occurs, telling me that my thread has a problem.

I have another button without a thread behind and it performs the action perfectly if I click it another time.

Can somebody tell me where the problem is? I tried to close the thread by using `Thread.currentThread().stop();` but it still does not work.

Here is my sample code,

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

        if(chooser == null){
           String message = "No file chosen. Please choose your file.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "WiresharkHelper",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }
        else if(chooser != null){
        jTabbedPane4.setSelectedIndex(1);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        }
    }
JOptionPane opt = new JOptionPane("Application is running", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{});//I put this in global for my thread2 to dispose my dialog
    JDialog dlg = opt.createDialog("Warning");
    Thread thread2 = new Thread () {
  public void run () {
        dlg.setVisible(true);
  }
};
    Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
  public void run () {
    //code running
    dlg.dispose();
  }
};
```

Comment: what is the exact error message

Comment: You should provide your code in the way explained in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: JDialog - looks like swing to me. If you are running thread which invokes method on component, it must be run within UI thread context. Try running your thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` or `invokeAndWait(Runnable)`

Answer (score 0):

Thread.currentThread().stop(); is @Deprecated [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop())

Try the following

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

or

```
private volatile boolean stopRequested = false;

public void run() {
  while (!stopRequested) {
    ...
  }
}

public void requestStop() {
  stopRequested = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My observations:

1. you are invoking `Thread.currentThread().stop()` on UI thread
   itself, delete this line
2. thread2 is useless, delete it
3. invoke thread1 via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(thread1)`
4. you are starting two threads and you have no way of saying, which will run first. I do not remember Swing that well now, but I would be surprised if first disposing dialog and then calling `setVisible(true)` would do something good

Comment: I have code that running in thread2, I just didn't copy it to here. If I wan to remain the thread2 and I also wan to display the dialog and make it close automatically once thread2 finished running, any suggestion? or is there any way that combine it?

Comment: I would start thread2 first then and then call `join()` on it. If it has some component related operations, then invoke it via `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`